# ESXi 5.1 Multipathing Polciy - Script to change all policies at once

Tags: esxi, esx

I'm looking to create a script to change all of the multipathing policies from MRU to round robin.  I realize you can do it the following way:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2000552

However, I am looking for an easier to do it all at once as opposed to 64+ LUN's and 6 hosts.  Is there a way to do all of the LUN's or hosts at once?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [vSphere powercli multipath policy script examples](http://runningvm.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/vsphere-powercli-multipath-policy-script-examples/). Among others, there's a script "to connect to a Virtual Center server and set the mulitpathing policy for all datastores on all hosts in a Cluster to Round Robin".